# Merge with datetime compare in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge

I am having a temporary table (Table T) and another table having final data (tale F).

I need to compare a key field (tin here) and if record already exists and record creation date is older than the one in T,

I want to update the record in F.

If the record is not available in `T` i want to replace it.

I have used merge as given below -

```
MERGE Digitization329 AS NF
USING 
    ( SELECT    *
      FROM      TMP_Npr
    ) AS NT
ON NF.Tin = NT.Tin
WHEN MATCHED AND NF.[RCRD_CRN_DATE] < NT.[RCRD_CRN_DATE]
    THEN 
        UPDATE
      SET       [FULLNAME] = NT.FULLNAME ,
                [FATHERNAME] = NT.FATHERNAME ,
                [MOTHERNAME] = NT.MOTHERNAME ,
                [SPOUSENAME] = NT.SPOUSENAME
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
        INSERT  (
                  [TIN] ,
                  [FTIN] ,
                  [FULLNAME] ,
                  [FATHERNAME] ,
                  [MOTHERNAME] ,
                  [SPOUSENAME]
                )
      VALUES    ( NT.TIN ,
                  NT.FTIN ,
                  NT.FULLNAME ,
                  NT.FATHERNAME ,
                  NT.MOTHERNAME ,
                  NT.SPOUSENAME
                );
```

`RCRD_CRN_DATE` in both the tables are of `datetime` type.

However i always get duplicate records in the F Table.

I am  unable to find out the reason why WHEN MATCHED AND NF.[RCRD_CRN_DATE] < NT.[RCRD_CRN_DATE]  is not working.

Thanks.

My T table contains three records

```
  tin RCRD_CRN_DATE ...
  123 10-11-2013-12.20.30
  123 10-11-2013-12.20.35
  345 10-11-2013-01.10.10
```

After the operation F table has all three records.

Comment: Show some sample data from both tables and indicate which row(s) should be inserted vs. updated (e.g. show before and after). We can't see what "duplicate records" you're getting.

Comment: Aaron is right, we'd need to see the data you are working with to suggest any solutions.